# Python ssocket on gunicorn webserver

Tags: python, gunicorn

I m working on a Flask webserver that have a ssocket server connection on embbedded linux board. When I set gunicorn web service configuration like this;

`ExecStart=gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:443 --workers 4 --thread 3 --worker-class=gthread --timeout 600 wsgi:app`

Socket is not connecting. I took this error;

```
[493]: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

When I set wokers number at 1 its connecting. I need some performance this webserver.

How Can I configure gunicorn ?